# В предложении "А что он подарил другу?" где подлежащее?

Tags: синтаксис

Дано предложение: "А что он подарил другу?" Вопрос: "Где здесь подлежащее?"

Answer (score 4):

***А что он подарил другу?***

Он — подлежащее, подарил — сказуемое, что — прямое дополнение, другу — косвенное дополнение.