# Вы лучше(,) чем кто-либо(,) знаете, какой вред этот продукт может нанести организму

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Вы лучше(,) чем кто-либо(,) знаете, какой вред этот продукт может нанести организму.

Нужно ли ставить запятые в отмеченных местах? Поиск по гугл-книгам дает смешанные результаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вопрос непростой.**

ЭТО ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС

1) В справочнике по пунктуации рассмотрено обособление оборота в сочетании  ***более чем***.

Этот оборот **обособляется при наличии сравниваемых предметов** и **не обособляется при их отсутствии** (в этом случае образуется неразложимое сочетание):

**Шут** необходим толпе **более, чем герой** (М. Горький).

Таким образом тайна была сохранена **более чем полудюжиною** заговорщиков (А. Пушкин).

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_68&layout=item

2) Оборот ***лучше чем*** МОЖНО РАЗОБРАТЬ ПО ТОМУ ЖЕ ПРИНЦИПУ. В приведенном предложении два сравниваемых предмета (вы, кто-либо), поэтому обособление оборота рекомендуется:

Вы **лучше, чем кто-либо,** знаете, какой вред этот продукт может нанести организму.

Именно вариант с обособлением встречается чаще всего.

А ЭТО ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ (АНАЛИЗ СИТУАЦИИ И ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ ВАРИАНТОВ БЕЗ ОБОСОБЛЕНИЯ)

3) **А другие варианты, они неправильны?**

Здесь возникает вопрос о влиянии на обособление других факторов, в частности структуры предложения, позиции оборота и его  распространенности (это учитывается при обособлении оборотов с союзом КАК).

И вот с учетом этих факторов можно предположить, что оборот в  некоторых случаях может не обособляться,  что связано с переносом логического ударения на оборот:

Вы **лучше чем кто-лИбо знаете,** какой вред этот продукт может нанести организму (ударение падает на оборот).

А ЭТО ПРИМЕРЫ С ВАРИАНТАМИ

**Примеры:**

Поэты знают об этом **лУчше,** **чем кто-лИбо.** [Елена Сигачева. Жизнь ― только слово (2002) // «Весть» (Калуга), 2002.08.15]

Уж он-то **лУчше, чем кто-лИбо**, знает, что реальные расходы партий на избирательную кампанию в отчеты все равно не попадут. [Валерий Выжутович.  2003]

Никогда не сходясь с этими двумя чуждыми ему художниками, Микельанджело скорбел о них, так как **лучше чем кто-лИбо** сознавал, как неизмеримо велика была утрата для родины и для искусства. [Ал. Алтаев (1955)]

Думаю, что Вы **лучше чем кто-лИбо** другой знаете, что со своими инженерными способностями он мог бы зарабатывать значительно больше, если бы целью его жизни были деньги. [П. Л. Капица. Письма (1935).

**Примечание.** Примеры без обособления взяты из текстов до 1956 года, но они соответствуют интонации (возможно, что в дальнейшем обособление стало формальным).

В современных текстах можно встретить необособленный оборот ***более чем кто-либо***: **Более чем кто-либо** он понимал, что единственный механизм влияния власти на общественное мнение и общественного мнения на власть ― периодическая печать. [Виктор Лопатников. 2003.09.03]

Answer (score 3):

*Вы лучше, **чем кто-либо,** знаете, какой вред этот продукт может нанести организму.*

Мне думается, что в этом предложении имеется обычный сравнительный оборот, который по правилам требует обособления.
[«Лучше, чем»](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/luchshe-chem.html)

*Анна Андреевна, вы лучше, чем кто-либо на этом свете, знаете, что...* (В. Савин)
*Я уверен, что Вы лучше, чем кто-либо, знаете за собой какие-то недостатки* (П. Ф. Беликов).

*Вы лучше, чем кто-либо другой, знаете, что находящиеся под вашим командованием солдаты страдают и умирают не за справедливое дело* (Ф. Кастро).

*Вы лучше, чем кто-либо, знаете, что только независимое, самостоятельное, уверенное в себе государство может гарантированно обеспечить подлинную защиту прав и свобод граждан.*
[В. В. Путин (на встрече с судьями конституционного суда)](http://lawinrussia.ru/content/vstrecha-vladimira-putina-s-sudyami-konstitucionnogo-suda)

Comment: Официальными (наиболее авторитетными) источниками принято считать ПАС, Розенталя и справочник Грамоты.ру. В первых двух нет рекомендаций по этому сочетанию, а Грамота.ру  дает два варианта для сочетания "более чем". Автор вопроса отмечает, что сочетание "лучше чем"  в разных текстах также имеет варианты. Поэтому мне не думается. что это ОБЫЧНЫЙ сравнительный оборот, здесь нужен более серьезный анализ, чем простое мнение. Вы уверены, что во всех случаях требуется обособление? Вы гарантируете, что это формальное решение является единственно верным? На чем основано Ваше мнение?

Comment: Я уже сказала, что вариант с обособлением встречается чаще всего. Вы ПОВТОРЯЕТЕ эту информацию или  хотите сказать, что других вариантов быть не может? Вот это мне неясно. В Сети много разных учебных сайтов, не стоит считать изложенную там информацию абсолютно достоверной.

Comment: Sharon, я не обладаю **такими глобальными** знаниями, как Вы. Поэтому далеко не углубляюсь, просто выражаю свое мнение: именно в ЭТОМ предложении есть ОБЫЧНЫЙ сравнительный оборот, который НАДО обособить. Привожу какую-никакую ссылку и примеры, отличные от Ваших. А предложения тридцатых-пятидесятых  годов? Я бы и в них поставила запятые.

Comment: @Sharon Да, кстати, Вы ведь тоже НЕ ВСЕГДА приводите в своих ответах доскональные объяснения. Иногда ПРОСТО констатируете — и всё, без каких-либо разъяснений, серьёзных анализов, вопросов к членам предложения или указаний на связи между ними. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450145/В-предложении-А-что-он-подарил-другу-где-подлежащее/450146#450146 Никто ведь не возмущается!

Comment: @Sharon *>> а Грамота.ру дает два варианта для сочетания "более чем"* **Лучше, чем кто-либо.** Где там "более чем"?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Вы. вероятно, хотели бы заключить "глобальные" в кавычки, я поняла Ваш посыл. И Ваш удаленный комментарий я тоже видела. Ну что ж, друзья, поздравляю Вас с победой. Наш форум стал проще и лучше. Нужно давать по возможности простые и короткие ответы, ничего не стоит усложнять. И обоснование нужно простое: (1) конечно, надо обособлять; (2) я так думаю, что надо (на одном сайте так написано); (3) да и вопрос-то простой, выеденного яйца не стоит. Вот это лицо форума, это приветствуется и ни в коем случае не осуждается. Приятно, что Вы сдружились, объединились и нашли общий язык.

Comment: @Sharon Нет, лучше умствовать на пустом месте и из-за этого делать ошибки, за которые и в школе двойки ставят. Вы так и не ответили, где в вопросе нашли "более чем".

Comment: Грамота.ру приводит такой пример: Шут необходим толпе БОЛЕЕ, ЧЕМ герой. М. Горький, Жизнь Клима Самгина. Я С ЭТИМ СОГЛАСНА, здесь дается обособление. Но этот оборот может не обособляться, если при другой структуре предложения переходит в неразложимое сочетание. Можно предположить, что оборот "лучше чем" тоже имеет подобные ограничения. Непонятно? Ну и ладно, можно прожить и не думая над лишними проблеами. Я ответила на вопрос, спасибо за внимание, но мне отвечать не надо.

Comment: *>> Можно предположить, что оборот "лучше чем" тоже имеет подобные ограничения.* С какого перепугу?